# how to determine how much time needed when calling moveItemAtURL:toURL: or replaceItemAtURL:WithItemAtURL:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsfilemanager

When moving file from one place to another, or when replacing file, I always use the methods `moveItemAtURL:toURL:` or `replaceItemAtURL:WithItemAtURL:`  from `NSFileManager`.

When calling these methods, I want to determine how much time needed, so that I can use the `NSProgressIndicator` to tell users how long it's going to take. Just like when you are moving file using OSX, it tells u how much time remaining.

I have looked at the apple doc but couldn't find any information regarding this.
Wondering if this can be implemented, please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't know in advance haw long it going to take. What you can do is compute the "percent complete" while you are copying the file. But to do that you need to use lower level APIs. You can use NSFileManagers `attributesOfItemAtPath:error` to get the file size and NSStreams for doing the copying (there are so many way to do this). Percent complete is `bytesWritten / totalBytesInFile`.

--- Edit: added sample code as a category on NSURL with a callback block passing the total number of bytes written, percen complete and estimated time left in seconds.

```
#import <mach/mach_time.h>

@interface NSURL(CopyWithProgress)<NSObject>
- (void) copyFileURLToURL:(NSURL*)destURL withProgressBlock:(void(^)(double, double, double))block;
@end

@implementation NSURL(CopyWithProgress)

- (void) copyFileURLToURL:(NSURL*)destURL
        withProgressBlock:(void(^)(double, double, double))block
{
    ///
    // NOTE: error handling has been left out in favor of simplicity
    //       real production code should obviously handle errors.
    NSUInteger fileSize = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:self.path error:nil].fileSize;

    NSInputStream  *fileInput  = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:self];
    NSOutputStream *copyOutput = [NSOutputStream outputStreamWithURL:destURL append:NO];

    static size_t bufferSize = 4096;
    uint8_t *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    size_t   bytesToWrite;
    size_t   bytesWritten;
    size_t   copySize = 0;
    size_t   counter  = 0;

    [fileInput open];
    [copyOutput open];

    uint64_t time0 = mach_absolute_time();

    while (fileInput.hasBytesAvailable) {
        do {
            bytesToWrite = [fileInput read:buffer maxLength:bufferSize];
            bytesWritten = [copyOutput write:buffer maxLength:bytesToWrite];
            bytesToWrite -= bytesWritten;
            copySize     += bytesWritten;
            if (bytesToWrite > 0)
                memmove(buffer, buffer + bytesWritten, bytesToWrite);
        }
        while (bytesToWrite > 0);

        if (block != nil && ++counter % 10 == 0) {
            double percent  = (double)copySize / fileSize;
            uint64_t time1  = mach_absolute_time();
            double elapsed  = (double)(time1 - time0)/NSEC_PER_SEC;
            double estTimeLeft = ((1 - percent) / percent) * elapsed;
            block(copySize, percent, estTimeLeft);
        }
    }

    if (block != nil)
        block(copySize, 1, 0);
}

@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/eric/bin/data/english-words.txt"];
        NSURL *destURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/eric/Desktop/english-words.txt"];

        [fileURL copyFileURLToURL:destURL withProgressBlock:^(double bytes, double pct, double estSecs) {
            NSLog(@"Bytes=%f, Pct=%f, time left:%f s",bytes,pct,estSecs);
        }];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Bytes=40960.000000, Pct=0.183890, time left:0.000753 s
Bytes=81920.000000, Pct=0.367780, time left:0.004336 s
Bytes=122880.000000, Pct=0.551670, time left:0.002672 s
Bytes=163840.000000, Pct=0.735560, time left:0.001396 s
Bytes=204800.000000, Pct=0.919449, time left:0.000391 s
Bytes=222742.000000, Pct=1.000000, time left:0.000000 s
```

Comment: finding out the pct complete is fine too. @aLevelOfIndirection can you please provide some sample code (or please include a link of the sample code) of how this can be done. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I mostly concur with CRD. I just want to note that under certain common circumstances, both `-moveItemAtURL:toURL:` and `-replaceItemAtURL:WithItemAtURL:...` are very fast. When the source and destination are on the same volume, no data has to be copied or moved, only metadata. When the volume is local (as opposed to network-mounted), this typically takes negligible time. That said, it is appropriate to plan for the possibility that they could take significant time.

Also, he mentioned the `copyfile()` routine for moving files. A copy followed by deleting the original is the necessary approach when moving a file between volumes, but the `rename()` system call will perform a move within a volume without needing to copy anything. So, a reasonable approach would be to try `rename()` first and, if it fails with `EXDEV`, fall back to `copyfile()`.

Finally, the `exchangedata()` system call can be used as part of a reimplementation of `-replaceItemAtURL:WithItemAtURL:...`.

I don't recommend the approach suggested by aLevelOfIndirection because there are a lot of fiddly details about copying files. It's much better to rely on system libraries than trying to roll your own. His example completely ignores file metadata (file dates, extended attributes, etc.), for example.

Comment: Any sample code to demostrate of using copyfile, rename(0 and exchangedata()? as I'm not too familiar with c. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The methods `moveItemAtURL:toURL:` and `replaceItemAtURL:WithItemAtURL:` are high-level operations. While they provide the semantics you want for the move/replace, as you've found out, they don't provide the kind of feedback you wish during those operations.

Apple is in the process of changing lower-level file handling routines, many are now marked as deprecated in 10.8, so you'll want to pick carefully what you choose to use. However at the lowest levels, system calls (manual section 2) and library functions (manual section 3), there are functions that you can use that are not being deprecated.

One option, there are others, is the function `copyfile` (manual section 3) which will copy a file or folder hierarchy and provides for a progress callback. That should give you most of the semantics of `moveItemAtURL:toURL:` along with progress, but you'll need to do more work for `replaceItemAtURL:WithItemAtURL:` to preserve safety (no data loss in case of error).

If that doesn't meet all your needs you can also look additionally at the low-evel `stat` and friends to find out file sizes etc.

HTH